# Perl : Unable to load a module

Tags: perl, powershell

i am using this `PowerShell::Cmdlet` module to run powershell commands from a perl script but i keep getting this error ,even though i have placed the module in the `lib` folder

> `Can't locate object method "new" via package "PowerShell" at`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PowerShell::Cmdlet;

my $res ;

my $command = PowerShell
->new('Get-ChildItem', [Image => '\\host1\det\mws\cm\seq\ws\*\*\*'])
->command();
 my $result = `$command`;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `use PowerShell;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using wrong parameter for getchilditem (image instead of path) and the module should be changed to PowerShell as @ikegami has mentioned.Can you try this :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PowerShell;

my $res ;

my $command = PowerShell
->new('Get-ChildItem', [Path => '\\\\10.0.0.1\\testshare\\'],[include => '*.txt'],[recurse => ''])
->command();
 my $result = `$command`;

print($result)
```

Comment: i got this error `Global symbol "$logger" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $logger"?) at C:/Perl64/lib/PowerShell.pm line 32.`

Comment: and also another error was `can't locate PowerShell.pm` in the `lib` folder , but i have put the `pl` file in the `lib` folder

Comment: @kewin which perl implementation are you using (active state or strawberry)?

Comment: i am using active state

Comment: @kewin after running cpan PowerShell . can you check is there powershell.pm in c:\perl64\lib else you might need to copy powershell.pm and powershell folder from C:\Perl64\cpan\build\PowerShell-1.00-<some value>\lib. the above snippet is working fine for me with activestate so I am guessing a module related issue

Comment: i got it, i had install this `Log::Any ` module  and how can i add an UNC path in the `path` parameter,say  `\\host80\fipt\os\tws\sqwe\logs\*\*\*  -Filter  "all.jml`

Comment: I am able to list all the directories present in the path but when i include the `include` parameter it returns nothing i also tried `[include => '*']` it doesn't return anything

Comment: and where did you find the documentation for that

Comment: @kewin I couldn't find much documentation, educated guess :-).can you tell me the file patterns you are looking for? if you want all.jml then [include => 'all.jml']

Comment: the include parameter works , is the `recurse` same as depth

Comment: @kewin if this helped you , can you accept it as answer as this will help people who will have similar problem